# ImportError: No module named 'zbar' continues after installing libzbar-dev

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi3, zbar

[image]

I'm already gave the comand

```
apt-get install libzbar-dev
```

and the other one

```
pip install zbar
```

But it still not working. Plese help me, I'm trying trying and trying but still nor work. Thanks since now.

Comment: Please make the question clear.

Comment: I'm trying to use zbar with python on raspberry pi 3 model b. I instaled it, with the comand: sudo apt-get zbar tools. And after this I tried to call the zbar on python, with import zbar. But didn't work. So I search over internt and I found that we needed to install libzbar-dev. So I did it. But it still not working. When I try to run the program gives the error ImportError: No module named 'zbar'.

Comment: Please add additional information **inside** your question by **editing** it, not by commenting. Thanks.